# Set HTML Date Picker With Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, html, datepicker

I'm trying to take a date from a date picker and then output the date to the value of a second picker.

I should work like this,

1. fill in dateIn
2. press button
3. date displayed on dateOut picker

My code:

```
<input id="dateIn"  name="dateIn"  type="date"  value=""/>
<input id="dateOut" name="dateOut" type="date"  value=""/>

<button type="button" onclick="FunctionDate()">Click Me!</button>
```

Here is the function: (It does run when the button is pressed)

```
function FunctionDate() {   
    Document.getElementById("dateOut").value = Document.getElementById("dateIn").value;
}
```

The problem is in the function, but what should run in there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forgot the quotes around element ID's:

```
document.getElementById("dateOut").value = document.getElementById("dateIn").value;
```

And remove the `()` from the `.value` call. Just a tip, always have your console open when writing JS, you'll see the syntax errors.

Comment: Thankyou very much, and how do I get the console open in Dreamweaver?